# pyqt QTreeWidget signal on item drop

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, signals-slots, qtreewidget

I need to enable a button in my app whenever something is dropped to my custom QTreeWidget.

I sub-classed QTreeWidget to implement drag and drop of custom data. But I'm not able to find a way to get notified when something is dropped into my custom QTreeWidget. I couldn't find a QTreeWidget [signal](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html) to do this. Of course, the QTreeWidget's dropEvent() will be called each time something is dropped but that doesn't help much to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Here's where I instantiate the custom QTreeWidget that accepts drops from another widget,

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import MyTreeWidget

class TestWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(TestWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.myTreeWidget = MyTreeWidget.MyTreeWidget()
    ...
    #self.myTreeWidget.onItemDropped.connect(self.doSomethingOnItemDropped) <== I am looking for something like this

  def doSomethingOnItemDropped(self):
    # Enable certain button 

  ...
```

And then, here is how I sub-classed QTreeWidget,

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MyTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)

  def dropEvent(self, event): 
    if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-icon-and-text')):
      event.acceptProposedAction()
      data = event.mimeData().data("application/x-icon-and-text")
      stream= QtCore.QDataStream(data, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
      text = QtCore.QString()
      icon = QtGui.QIcon()
      stream >> text >> icon
      item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self)
      item.setText(0, text)
      item.setIcon(0, icon)
      self.addTopLevelItem(item)      
    else:
      event.ignore() 

  def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-icon-and-text')):
      event.accept()
    else:
      event.ignore() 

  def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-icon-and-text"):
      event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
      event.accept()
    else:
      event.ignore()
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE** : **This is what worked for me**

Based on comment by @ekhumoro I defined a custom signal itemDropped for my custom QTreeWidget which emits in dropEvent() event handler.

```
    import sys
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

    class MyTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):

      itemDropped = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

      def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTreeWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

      def dropEvent(self, event): 
        if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-icon-and-text')):
          event.acceptProposedAction()
          data = event.mimeData().data("application/x-icon-and-text")
          stream= QtCore.QDataStream(data, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
          text = QtCore.QString()
          icon = QtGui.QIcon()
          stream >> text >> icon
          item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self)
          item.setText(0, text)
          item.setIcon(0, icon)
          self.addTopLevelItem(item)
          self.itemDropped.emit()
        else:
          event.ignore()
```

And in my app,

```
    from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
    import MyTreeWidget

    class TestWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.myTreeWidget = MyTreeWidget.MyTreeWidget()
        self.myTreeWidget.itemDropped.connect(self.doSomethingOnItemDropped) 
        ...

      def doSomethingOnItemDropped(self):
        # Enable certain button 

      ...
```

Comment: Without actually going and looking myself, standard answer re missing signals: try looking for events also.  I assume you also clicked the link to see all inherited members?

Comment: I can't understand why you would think `dropEvent` doesn't help: it could hardly be better suited to what you want to do. Just [define your own](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal) `itemDropped` signal and emit it from `dropEvent` at whatever point you feel is appropriate.

Comment: @ekhumoro : You are right. I defined a new signal that emits it in dropEvent. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a custom signal and emit it from `dropEvent`:

```
class MyTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    itemDropped = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def dropEvent(self, event): 
        if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-icon-and-text')):
            ...
            self.itemDropped.emit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In PySide2 you can use this:

```
class MyTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):

    itemDropped = QtCore.Signal()

    def dropEvent(self, event): 
        if (event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-icon-and-text')):

            self.itemDropped.emit()
```